# Why does std::cin.getline not have an oveloaded method to take std::string?

Tags: c++, getline, cin

I'm curious about the technical reason for [cin.getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) and the [global getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) function being in different places.

What was the motivation for not simply defining all these function signatures for cin:

```
//THESE TWO EXIST
istream& cin::getline (char* s, streamsize n );
istream& cin::getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );

//THESE TWO COULD EXIST
istream& cin::getline (string &s);
istream& cin::getline (string &s, char delim );
```

Was it because other types may want to be added and they didn't want to marry the string to cin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't the std::fstream classes take a std::string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332/why-dont-the-stdfstream-classes-take-a-stdstring)

Comment: @wilhelmtell: This seems like a completely different question.

Comment: @UncleBens the question is very similar, even if the names are different. The answer should be (nearly) identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my answer for [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332/why-dont-the-stdfstream-classes-take-a-stdstring). It might be an oversight by the C++ Standard committee, but it can also be explained with dependency concerns. If the standard would require function overloads for `std::string` in the `<iostream>` header then it would require implementers to `#include<string>` in `<iostream>`. That's a dependency requirement, which would further slow down compiling anything that requires `<iostream>` -- even if a compilation unit doesn't itself need `std::string`.

Do note that on the other hand the `<string>` header has functions that take a reference to `std::basic_istream<>` and `std::basic_ostream<>`; but the standard also requires a header named `<iosfwd>` which forward-declares all IO facilities, making the `<string>` header dependable on the compile-time fast `<iosfwd>` header. A dependency the other way around would be much slower to compile.

Answer (score 4):

More or less. "They" probably didn't want to have [std::istream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/) depend on [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) in any way, probably to minimize [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_science%29).

Note that [std::getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) is defined in the `<string>` module.

Answer (score 0):

> There are several places where the C++
>   standard committee did not really
>   optimize the interaction between
>   facilities in the standard library.
>
> std::string and its use in the library
>   is one of these.
>
> One other example is std::swap. Many
>   containers have a swap member
>   function, but no overload of std::swap
>   is supplied. The same goes for
>   std::sort.
>
> I hope all these small things will be
>   fixed in the upcoming standard.

[-Christopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3186/christopher)

Adding this post I found in that other thread because it seems relevant and accepting an answer.