# Why should I use c_str() in functions

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, command-line-arguments

I am reading the book C++ Primer and at the file input output chapter it uses:

```
ifstream infile(ifile.c_str());
```

to open a file whose name is in the string `ifile`.

**I tried the code and it works perfectly even without `c_str()`.** So what is the point of using it?

**Should I use `c_str()` when I am trying to open a file from a command line argument?** I mean which is the correct usage:

```
ifstream fin( argv[1] )
```

or

```
ifstream fin( argv[1].c_str() )
```

Comment: do you get any compiler errors or warnings?

Comment: No it compiles without errors.

Comment: `argv[1]` usually refers to a `char*`, in which case `ifstream fin( argv[1].c_str() )` would be an error (pointers don't have member functions)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The constructor for `ifstream` used to only take a `const char *` (which is what the `c_str()` method provides.

I believe that there is a new constructor for it that takes a `std::string` in the upcoming standard, (edit) see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332/why-dont-the-stdfstream-classes-take-a-stdstring/62981#62981).

It could also be specific to your implementation.

Comment: +1 The latest copy of the upcoming standard document, which is a *Final Draft* (no semantic changes should be performed in the document prior to the approved standard) does have a constructor that takes a `const std::string&)

Answer (score 7):

That book is rather old (at least, the edition I have is rather old, and perhaps yours, too.) The `iostream` library is much older than STL and the `string` class; earlier vrsions of `iostream` didn't have the `string` constructor, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

`ifstream` constructor takes filename as a `const char *` rather than a C++ `string`. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/ifstream/). The `c_str()` member function returns a `const char *` pointer to the string.

edit: Maybe your compiler supports an overloaded version of this constructor or the standard got updated.

Comment: ***not*** `char*` ... `const char*` there's a huge difference

Comment: yes, but I thought maybe the emphasis here is on the `char *` part of it.