# FStream class and using strings as parameters

Tags: c++, string, text, parameters, fstream

```
Deneme::Deneme(string FileName){

 fstream textfile;
 textfile.open(FileName);
 }
```

This gives me an error, but when I type textfile.open("randomname");  instead of textfile.open(FileName); there seems to be no problem. Why is this? It might be an easy question but I'm a beginner and couldn't find the solution of this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332/why-dont-the-stdfstream-classes-take-a-stdstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fstreams only accept `const char*`. Use `textfile.open(FileName.c_str());` or `fstream textfile(FileName.c_str());` instead (although C++11 accepts `const std::string&`).
Here is a [handy site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream) to look up how the constructors and functions are declared.

Answer (score 0):

fstream's open method takes a const char pointer while you're passing in a std::string by value, I imagine this could be the error. Try:

```
textfile.open(FileName.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a standard C++ conforming system: C++2011 provides constructors and `open()` functions taking a `std::string const&`. For a pre-C++2011 system you need to use `name.c_str()` to pass to the file stream.