# Want to create many different files, but with different names

Tags: c++, string, file, file-io, io

I need to create a bunch of different files and I want to name them something like:

```
"signal1.dat", "signal2.dat", "signal3.dat", ... , "signal100.dat"
```

This is what I have so far

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::string out = "signal";
std::string format = ".dat";
std::string finalName;
int TrkNxtSig = 1;

...
[code]  
... 


ss << out << TrkNxtSig << format;
finalName = ss.str();
ofstream output(finalName); 
TrkNxtSig++;
```

I get this error

```
     error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(std::string&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/fstream:623: note: candidates are: std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ofstream(const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/fstream:608: note:                 std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ofstream() [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:84: note:                 std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
```

I'm not sure what that error message is telling me. What is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't the std::fstream classes take a std::string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332/why-dont-the-stdfstream-classes-take-a-stdstring)

Comment: BTW, if you upgrade your compiler it should start working.

Comment: Tags are there so that you don't need to provide them in your title (i.e. remove the `[C++]` from the title). Actual tags are more powerful as they allow for indexing and searching

Answer (score 2):

It's telling you that there's no constructor for `ofstream` that takes a `std::string` as parameter.

Use `ofstream output(finalName.c_str());` instead.

This has been fixed in C++11. If you're using gcc, try passing it `-std=c++0x`.