# Why does c_str() return the same value for two different strings?

Tags: c++, string

Given a simple file loading function,

```
std::string load_file(const std::string &filename) {
    std::ifstream     file(filename);
    std::string       line;
    std::stringstream stream;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        stream << line << "\n";
    }
    return stream.str();
}
```

Why does the following print the contents of `another_file` twice?

```
const char *some_file = load_file("some_file").c_str();
const char *another_file = load_file("another_file").c_str();
printf("%s", some_file);
printf("%s", another_file);
```

Comment: I don't that it's safe to call c_str() on return values without storing the string explicitly. Compare pointer values from some_file and another_file, I think they will be the same.

Comment: ifstream doesn't take std::string also, in C++11 it does. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542/2591612

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code is broken. You are calling `c_str()` on a temporary object that is immediately destroyed. Which means that the values returned by `c_str()` are invalid.

You need to make sure that the `std::string` objects returned survive at least as long as you hold on to the pointer returned by the call to `c_str()`. For example:

```
std::string some_file = load_file("some_file");
std::string another_file = load_file("another_file");
printf("%s", some_file.c_str());
printf("%s", another_file.c_str());
```

Answer (score 3):

In a line like this:

> ```
> const char *some_file = load_file("some_file").c_str();
> ```

`load_file()` returns a **temporary** `std::string`, and then `.c_str()` is called on this temporary.

When the temporary is alive, the pointer returned by `.c_str()` points to some meaningful string. But when the temporary "evaporates" (at the semicolon), then that same pointer is pointing to garbage.

The "garbage" may be the same string that the previous call to `load_file()` returned, so you have the effect that both raw pointers point to the same string.
But this is just a coincidence.
And your code has a bug.

String **classes** like `std::string` were invented as a convenient way to simplify the C++ programmer's life instead of using raw C string pointers. So, just use `std::string`s if you want to safely manage strings in C++.

Consider using `.c_str()` just *at the boundary* with C functions (including `printf()`).

So, you can refactor your code like this:

```
// load_file() returns a std::string, so just keep using std::string.
// Note that returning std::string is efficient thanks to RVO/NRVO 
// and C++11 move semantics. 
std::string some_file = load_file("some_file");

// Idem for this:
std::string another_file = load_file("another_file");

// Convert from std::string to raw C string pointers at the C boundary
printf("%s\n", some_file.c_str());
printf("%s\n", another_file.c_str());
```

Even some code like this would work fine:

```
printf("%s\n", load_file("some_file").c_str());
printf("%s\n", load_file("another_file").c_str());
```

In fact, note that in this case, even if you are using a temporary (i.e. the strings returned by `load_file()` are not copied to *named* `std::string` variables), the temporary is valid during the `printf()` call, so the raw pointer returned by `.c_str()` points to a valid string while `printf()` is doing its printing job.