# Why ifstream/ofstream does not work without c_str() function?

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

Basically, what I have is 2 constant string variables with names of input/output text files and 2 functions that take those strings as parameter. One function is for reading 1st file, while another is for writing to 2nd file.

Constants :

```
const string duom = "U2.txt";
const string rez = "rez.txt";
```

One of the functions :

```
void fileWrite(const string fn,int kieknuvaziavo,int kiekpristate,string paskutinis)
{
ofstream fout(fn.c_str());
fout << kiekpristate << " " << kieknuvaziavo << " " << paskutinis;
fout.close();
}
```

If I were to remove `.c_str()` from this line `ofstream fout(fn.c_str());` I'd get this error:

```
no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::basic_ofstream(const string&)'|
```

Here's part of main function:

```
int main()
{
    int kiekpristate = 0;
    int kieknuvaziavo = 0;
    string paskutinis;
    fileWrite(rez,kieknuvaziavo,kiekpristate,paskutinis);
    return 0;
}
```

Now if I were to take another route, and instead of using parameters for text file path, write it myself in ofstream, like this: `ofstream fout("rez.txt");` It would work perfectly fine. My question is why do I need `c_str()` function whenever I use function parameters for passing that variable? What does that function do? Isn't `fn` equal to `"rez.txt"`?

Comment: Maybe dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332/why-dont-the-stdfstream-classes-take-a-stdstring.  Do note that `"some text"` is not a `string`.  It is a c style string which is just and array of characters,

Comment: The overloads for `std::ifstream`/`std::ofstream` constructors, that take `std::string` were added in C++11 standard (previously they only accepted `char*`). Are you compiling with C++11 features enabled?

Comment: I have got no idea whether C++11 features are enabled or not, how can I check?

Comment: @Arkadijus Depends on your compiler. You didn't specify such information in the question itself. If you are using g++, you could compile with C++11, by using the `-std=c++11` command line argument.

Comment: I'm using CodeBlocks with GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: @Arkadijus GCC compiler version?

Comment: Where do i check?

Comment: @Arkadijus At your command line: `gcc --version`.

Comment: 'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Add `-v` to settings/compiler/compiler settings/other compiler options. Run a build. The version is somewhere there in the log, find it.

Comment: @Arkadijus -- In general, always know what tools and version of the tools you're using to build your programs.  Just don't blindly compile stuff and not know what you're running to do the job.

Comment: I don't really get what my compiler has to do with the question. Why do I have to use `c_str()` function? Why `ofstream fout("rez.txt")` isn't equal to `ofstream fout(fn)` where `fn` is `"rez.txt"`. I didn't understand what NathanOliver was trying to say me there, I'm only starting to learn C++

Comment: @n.m. Tried building with -v and without It, logs stay completely same.

Comment: @Arkadijus -- Codeblocks must know where `gcc` is located.  Go to your Codeblocks Preferences / Setup / Whatever and see what the command-line it's using to run the compiler.  CodeBlocks is **not** a compiler, it is running the compiler installed on your machine, and it has to know the full path of where to run gcc.exe.

Comment: "'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". google returns enough results to this query, the world doesn't need another hit.

Comment: It's 4.9.2 version I think.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie code::blocks does a reasonably good job hiding the path. One needs to know where to look.

Comment: So, I know my compiler version, whats next?

Comment: You either throw it away and install the newest version of mingw (6.x.y) or leave your current one and add `-std=c++11` to the compiler options. "Tried building with -v and without It, logs stay completely same" --- this generally cannot be true in this here universe. You are probably not looking at the build log but rather at the build messages (surprise, two different thins),

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I was looking at the right place, but nevermind that. Now that I've put that line in, It works without `c_str()` function. Should I forget about it now, or still continue using it? What are the chances that when I'll be taking exam from programming, the checking person will have this thing enabled?