# Writing to input and output files in c++

Tags: c++, string, function, file-io, compiler-errors

I cannot get my code to compile because it keeps telling me "error: no matching function for call" on line 16. Any advice? I am suppose to read the file and write all the vowels to an output file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string filename;    // to hold the file name
    ifstream inputfile; // input to a file


    // Get the file name
    cout << "Enter a file name: ";
    cin >> filename;

    // Open the file
    inputfile.open(filename); // LINE 16

    char vowel; // to store the vowels
    ofstream outputfile; // to write to the file

    // open file
    outputfile.open("vowels_.txt");

    while(inputfile.get(vowel)){
        //If the char is a vowel or newline, write to output file.
        if((vowel == 'a')||(vowel == 'A')||(vowel =='e')||(vowel =='E')||(vowel =='i')||(vowel =='I')||(vowel =='o')||(vowel =='O')||(vowel =='u')||(vowel =='U')||(vowel =='\n') && !inputfile.eof())
            outputfile.put(vowel);

    }

    inputfile.close();
    outputfile.close();



}
```

Comment: Line 17 is a blank line.

Comment: @immibis line 16, sorry

Comment: I guess it is the open() call. You need to pass a character pointer, like: `inputfile.open(filename.c_str());`

Comment: Or compile with C++11 or later enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
inputfile.open(filename);
```

to this:

```
inputfile.open(filename.c_str());
```

since `filename` is an `std::string`, and [`fstream::open`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/) takes `const char* filename` as a parameter.

Calling [`string:c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) returns `const char*` from `std::string`.

---

C++11 does not need this, since `fstream::open` is overloaded to take an `std::string` as well. Compile with `-std=c++11` flag to enable c++11.

---

PS: [Why don't the std::fstream classes take a std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332/why-dont-the-stdfstream-classes-take-a-stdstring) (Pre-C++1)

Comment: OH OKAY. THANK YOU

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Any insight on *why* you can't use `std::string`?

Comment: @PasserBy you mean with `fstream::open`? It has to do with the function's prototype, pre-C++11 and post.

Comment: Yes, but I meant what was the original consideration that made it lack such an overload?