# Does fstream take a constant character array as a parameter or a dynamic one?

Tags: c++, function, file-manipulation

I am trying to send an `fstream` object to a function, and I provided the name of the file as a string. Now I want to type-cast the string into a character array because `fstream` takes a character array. However, I am wondering whether to make it static or constant or not. Also, if I wanted to make it static, should I use `static_cast<const char*>` or should I just use `str.c_str()`?

I searched the Internet but wasn't successful finding the answer I needed.

Comment: Also you can just pass the `std::string` without having to use `c_str`. Note that `fstream` has a ctor that takes a `std::string` so your assumption that it can only take character array is wrong. Also finding and reading documentation is important part of being a programmer. The first search on web, suggests many docs like [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream)

Comment: It doesn't matter(whether a const char array or dynamic one) as long as it is null terminated.

Comment: Further to what has already been said `static_cast<const char*>` is definitely the wrong answer. `static_cast` does not make things static which is a meaningless concept in this situation. What counts is a null terminated string, not whether that string is 'dynamic' or 'static'.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to type cast the string into character array because fstream takes character array.

Your assumption that `fstream` only takes a character array is **wrong**. Starting from C++11, it also has a ctor that takes a `std::string`. So you don't need to use `c_str` or any cast as you can just directly use `std::string`.

From [std::fstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream):

```
explicit basic_fstream( const std::string& filename,

                        std::ios_base::openmode mode
                            = std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out );
```

---

[Why don't the std::fstream classes take a std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332/why-dont-the-stdfstream-classes-take-a-stdstring)

Comment: "*It also has a ctor that takes a std::string*" - yup, and it has done so for over a decade since C++11.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, added "starting from C++11"